# Angular bootstrap datepicker start date function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have this:

```
            <a href="#" data-bs-datepicker
               data-date-startDate="{{startDate(task)}}" data-ng-model="task.plannedEndDate"
               rel="tooltip" data-placement="left"
               title="${message(code: "dashboard.todosAndTasks.hint.editDueDate")}">
                {{task | dateIndication}}
            </a>
```

and the function:

```
    $scope.startDate = function(task) {
        var d = new Date(task.plannedStartDate);
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var m = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
        console.log(m);
        return m;
    };
```

The function gets called, I get a correct date-string logged in my console, but in the datepicker js, if I log the date received by this 'startDate' parameter, it's the actual string "{{startDate(task)}}" -> startDate automatically set to "today".

Why in the world does this happen?

++ only using data-date-startDate="startDate(task)", passess the string "startDate(task)" to the datepicker.js

Why!!?

Comment: please provide a fiddle on your problem

Comment: What is not clear? I'm relatively new to angular and don't really know how to transpose a 500 line js and 500 line html in just a simple example. Sorry about this -.-

Comment: you should build a simple example which represents your problem. this will help us help you ;)

Comment: maybe you can extend this one: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10320/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-bs-datepicker
           start-date="{{startDate(task)}}" data-ng-model="task.plannedEndDate"
           rel="tooltip" data-placement="left"
           title="${message(code: "dashboard.todosAndTasks.hint.editDueDate")}">
            {{task | dateIndication}}
 </a>
```